# Show that 1/n can be a bound for the probability of geting a minimum in the drawn n+1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

The question is as follows, suppose (${z_0,z_1,z_2..z_n}$) are independent random variables drawn from the same distribution F.Define the minimum of this set has a ($a=\min(z_0,z_1..z_n)$).I want to show that the probability of next drawn from the distribution (so that represents $z_{n+1}$) being inferior to $a$ is inferior to $\frac{1}{n}$

Show that:
$$Prob(z<a) < \frac{1}{n} $$

Things that I have tried and dueled, it is not difficult to see that the minimum has the pdf ($Prob(A<a) =1-(1-F(a)))^n$ so it has a probability density function off  $nf(a))(1-F(a))^{n-1}$

So to explicitly compute the required probability we can do something as follows: and calculate :
 $$ Prob(z<a) =\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}\int_{a=z}^{a=+\infty} f(a)f(z)dadz=\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}\int_{a=z}^{a=+\infty} nf(z)f(a)(1-F(a))^{n-1}dadz$$

the only bound that I can take from this is putting F(a) = 0 in the integral witch gives

$$ Prob(z<a) <= n\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}\int_{a=z}^{a=+\infty} f(z)f(a)dadz = n\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}f(z)[F(+\infty)-F(z)]dz= n\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}f(z)[1-F(z)]=n(1-\int_{z=-\infty}^{z=+\infty}f(z)F(z)dz) =\frac{n}{2}$$

evaluating this integral by parts:
$$\int f(z)F(z)dz= F(z)^2-\int f(z)F(z)dz$$ which gives
$$\int f(z)F(z)dz = \frac{F(z)^2}{2} $$
evaluating it in extremes that gives $\frac{1}{2}$ . So in my defense the value for n=2 seems nice xp

I believe I am attacking the problem in the wrong way , any suggestion would be very helpful. (note I also am not sure if I formulated correctly the problem).

Well I guess that now I solve it , if i don't say (F(a) = 0),Its visible that that integrals can be simplified to arrive to the right answer. you can integrate $f(a)(1-F(a))^n$ rather easily , and then you have another similar integral and you arrive at $\frac{1}{n+1}$ still probably was a overkil

Comment: If you can assume the variables are not discrete, i.e. $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, P(z=r) =0$, then the problem is easy.  There is $0$ prob that any two values are equal, and subject to that, $z_{n+1}$ is the smallest with prob ${1 \over n+1}$ by symmetry.

Comment: im not understanding what the symmetry implies,and what you mean by simmetry . can you develop a little ?

Comment: It means the problem is invariant under permutation of the variables. Since all variables are on an equal footing they must all have the same probability of being the least. If the probability that two of them are equal is $0$, then the $n+1$ probabilities for one of them to be the least must add up to $1$, so they must all be $\frac1{n+1}$.

Comment: If the distribution is continuous, then it is always true that $P(z<a)=\frac{1}{n+2}.$ This is because the probability of any element of $n+2$ identical random independent variables being the smallest is the same.

Comment: It seems like you have $P(z<a)\leq \frac{1}{n+2}$ because $P(z<a)$ is the probability that $z$ is the least element of the $z_0,\dots,z_{n},z$ which is $\frac{1}{n+2}$ times the probability that there is a unique least element of $z_0,\dots,z_n,z.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(z<a)$ is the same as the probability that $z_0,\dots,z_n,z_{n+1}$ has a unique minimum value $z_{n+1}.$ But if the values $z_0,\dots,z_n,z_{n+1}$ come from identical independent random variables, then given that there is a unique minimum, the probability that it is $z_{n+1}$ is $\frac{1}{n+2}.$

So if $q$ is the probability that $n+2$ of these i.i.d. have a unique minimum, then:

$$P(z_{n+1}<a)=\frac{q}{n+2}\leq \frac{1}{n+2}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

Note that when the distribution is continuous, then the probability that two of the $z_i$ are equal is zero, and thus we have $q=1$ and $P(z_{n+1}<a)=\frac{1}{n+2}.$